# How to describe the dynamics of this gamble?

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-walk, ergodic-theory, gambling

Suppose you have a $100 and you are offered a chance to play a game involving a fair coin toss:

- If you throw heads your wealth increases by 50%.
- If you throw tails your wealth decreases by 40%.

Assume that there is no upper bound to your wealth, i.e., you play the game until you are bankrupt. Let's assume that bankruptcy is an absorbing state and it is reached when your wealth is less than a dollar.

How one might describe the dynamics of your wealth when you go from coin toss $n$ to $n+1$. Moreover, what is the probability that you have increased your wealth after $N$ tosses?

Comment: How about taking the log of the wealth?

Comment: What do you mean "describe the dynamics"?  It seems you have described it.  Note that your wealth after $n$ tosses only depends on the number of heads among those $n$ as long as you do not go bankrupt.

Comment: Where can I go to play this game?

Comment: What I really wanted to find is the probability that after N tosses you have increased your wealth. Of course I realize as N goes to infinity the probability of bankruptcy is close to 1. Considering that this game is non-ergodic I was wondering how to show that the probability of increasing your wealth is smaller the more tosses you make.

Comment: Take the log. You get a classic random walk. Using the convolution, you should obtain the PMF at every step. Can you take it from there? If not, consult a book on (discrete-time, continuous-space) Markov processes.

Comment: @saulspatz Just curious. If I may ask, why do you want to play it?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo If I understand it right, it's a fair game, but the house pays $5$ to $4$.

Comment: @saulspatz $$x_{k+1} = \begin{cases} \frac32 x_k & \text{ if heads}\\ \frac35 x_k & \text { if tails}\end{cases}$$ Since $\frac32 \cdot  \frac35 < 1$ isn't this contractive? Am I missing something?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'm really confused now.  If I have $\$10$ and I win then I have $\$15$ but if I lose I have $\$6$.  That means I bet $4$ to win $5$.  How can that be disadvantageous on an even-money chance?

Comment: @saulspatz The expected value of each gamble is \begin{equation} EV=1.5*0.5+0.6*0.5=1.05\end{equation} However I modeled this game in python and found that if 30 players make 100 tosses almost all of them will become poorer than they were before. I guess that this happens because if you throw the dice N times, with N approaching infinity, you will get equal number of heads and tails. In this case your wealth is: \begin{equation} 1.5^{\frac{N}{2}} \times 0.6^{\frac{N}{2}}=0.9^{\frac{N}{2}}\end{equation} This means that on each coin toss you are really losing money.

Comment: @nipohc88 That doesn't make sense to me.  The expectation on each toss is positive.  The expectation on a sequence of tosses is the sum of the expectations on each toss.  By linearity, it must be positive.

Comment: @nipohc88 Okay, I see.  The outliers who win a lot win vast fortunes, but most people go broke.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, the expectation is positive but it does not matter for you as an individual. Suppose you get a heads and then a tails, your wealth is 1.5*0.6=0.9. I suppose a similar example is that of a russian roulette with a large payoff if you survive. Suppose 100 people play and the gun has 99 empty bullets and 1 real bullet. The expeected value of this will be positive as 99 people will become much wealthier. However, this expected value is irrelevant for you as a player, because if you play this game over and over again at some point you will die and be ruined.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, exactly as n approaches infinity total wealth has increased due to outliers who have made yuuge amounts of money, but probably 99.99999% of people have gone broke. So it probably is not a good game.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'm sorry if this is asking too much, but I am only a high school student and my understanding of probability is not particularly advanced. Could you explain what you mean by taking the log of wealth, as well as how to model the random walk?

Answer (score 1):

Now that I finally understand the problem, I have a suggestion for approximating a solution.  Change the rules so that the game ends either when the player goes bankrupt or when he has played $N$ times.  Now the chain is finite, with two absorbing states, and we can compute the time to absorption and the probability of absorption in each state by standard methods.  Since we know that the number of steps to absorption in the second absorbing state is $N$, and we also know the probability of absorption in that state, we can easily compute the average time to absorption in the first state.

The transient states are of the form $(w,\ell)$ meaning $\ell$ losses and $w$ wins, where $w+\ell<N$.  Not all possibilities appear, because $\left(\frac35\right)^5<\frac1{10}$ so any player who has lost $5$ times more than he has won has gone bankrupt.

My thought is to try it for various values of $N$, until it stops changing.  The main programming challenge is constructing the transition matrix.

Thanks for this programming problem.  It will help beguile my isolation today.

---

Suppose we make a cutoff of $M$ rolls. Let $X$ be the average number of rolls until the game ends, whether by bankruptcy or cutoff, let $B$ be the event of bankruptcy, and $C$ the event of cutoff.  We have 
$$\begin{align}
E(X)&=\Pr(B)E(X|B)+\Pr(C)E(X|C)\\
&=(1-\Pr(C))E(X|B)+\Pr(C)M
\end{align}$$
My program uses standard method to compute $E(X)$ and $\Pr(C)$ and then uses the above equation to solve for $E(X|B)$ the average time to bankruptcy among those players who went broke.

Here are the outputs from some successive runs:

```
 50 21.7034134587 .7138047863
100 31.2102201519 .8850110529
150 36.8849173664 .9436954032
200 40.4551201780 .9692561812
250 42.9567867921 .9828229050
300 44.6233194430 .9900053029
```

The first number is the cutoff value, the second is the average time to bankruptcy, and the third is the probability of bankruptcy.  It's starting to level off, and it's also starting to take a few minutes to run.  I'll try to run it overnight with large cutoffs, and let you know what happens tomorrow.

**EDIT**

Since I first posted this, I realized that there were a lot of superfluous states in my original script.  For example, with $M=100$, a player who wins $54$ games and loses $46$   does not go bankrupt, so once a player wins $54$ games, we know he will not go broke.  To compute the number of steps to absorption correctly, we just keep track of the number of games such players have played.  When $M=100$, this reduced the number of transient states from $2488$ to $1453$.  Of course, we could compute the average time to bankruptcy, by eliminating the cutoff state, and forcing players to go bankrupt, so that any player with $53$ wins would lose from then on.  This would reduce the number of transient states, by another $46$, but it would not allow computation of the probability of bankruptcy, which is nice to know.  The script below is the revised one.

Here's my script, if you want to check it, which I would appreciate.

```
'''
Player starts with bankroll of $100.  A fair coin is tossed;
if it comes up heads, bankroll increases by 50%.  If tails,
bankroll decreases by 40%.  Game ends if bankroll is less 
than $1, or after M plays.  What is the expected time
to bankruptcy?

In order to economize on the number of states, we compute
the number of wins W that will ensure the player from going
broke.  Once a player has W wins, we only track how many
games he's played.

Usage: python bankrupt.py M
'''
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
from sys import argv
import math
from resource import getrusage, RUSAGE_SELF

def bankrupt(state):
    win, lose = state
    if lose - win >= 5: return True
    return (3/2)**win * (3/5)**lose < 1/10

def maxWins(M):
    # player with this may wins won't go broke in M rolls
    alpha = math.log(3/2)
    beta = math.log(3/5)
    gamma = math.log(1/10)
    return math.ceil((gamma-beta*M)/(alpha-beta))

def test(M):
    count = 0
    states = []
    index = { }
    W = maxWins(M)

    for wins in range(W):
        for losses in range(M-wins):
            state = (wins, losses)
            if bankrupt(state):
                index[state] =-1
            else:
                states.append(state)
                index[state] = count
                count += 1
    for s in range(W, M):
        states.append((s,0))
        index[s,0] = count
        count += 1

    S = len(states)
    P = np.zeros((S+2, S+2))
    for i, (wins, losses) in enumerate(states):
        if W <= wins < M-1:
            P[i, index[wins+1,0]] = 1
            continue
        if wins == M-1:
            P[i, S+1] = 1
            continue
        w = (wins+1, losses)
        if wins == W-1 and sum(w) < M:
            P[i, index[W+losses,0]] = .5
        elif sum(w)== M:
            P[i,S+1] = .5
        else:
            P[i,index[w]] = .5
        loss = (wins, losses+1)
        if sum(loss)== M:
            # bankruptcy on roll N 
            # counts as a bankruptcy
            if bankrupt(loss):
                P[i,S] = .5
            else:
                 #stop whether a win or a loss
                P[i,S+1] = 1  
        else:
            idx = index[loss]
            if idx == -1:
                P[i, S] = .5
            else:
                P[i, idx] = .5 

    R = P[:S, S:]
    P = np.eye(S) - P[:S, :S]
    N = linalg.inv(P)   # fundamental matrix
    MEG =1024**2
    print(f"{S} states, {getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF)[2]//MEG} MB")

    # Expected time to absorption is sum of first row
    steps = sum(N[0,:])

    # Probability of N rolls is the (0,1) element of NR
    stop = N[0,:] @ R[:, 1]

    answer = (steps - M*stop)/(1-stop)
    return answer, 1-stop

M = int(argv[1])
steps, prob = test(M)
print(M, steps, prob)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise specified, if we are asked if something is a good bet we answer in terms of expected value.  If the expected value of the payoff is greater than the bet, we say it is good.  That is fine when you will play the game lots of times, so the law of large numbers kicks in and you confidently expect that much profit.  It is also fine for a small number of plays where the stake is not enough to change your life.  Being one dollar richer than you are now is probably about as nice as being one dollar poorer is bad.  When the stake becomes meaningful, at the extreme when it involves bankruptcy, the linear approximation is not a good one.  Losing all your money is a lot worse than doubling your money is good.  When people propose a bet where bankruptcy is one of the possible outcomes and say it is unconscionable, they are asking the wrong question.  They should define a utility function to be maximized, then we can take the expected value of that function and see if it is a good bet or not.

One utility function I have seen is the log of your money.  That has the nice properties of making bankruptcy infinitely bad and being convex upward so that increases in your fortune become progressively less interesting than losses, both of which are in accord with many people's perception.  Of course many other functions satisfy these two conditions, but logs are nice because they are easy to compute with.  In the case of this problem, a head adds $\log 1.5 \approx 0.405$ while tails adds $\log 0.6 \approx -.511$.  If this is your utility function, this is a bad bet each time.